# How to allow AWS IAM user to see decoded authorization messages when launching from the web console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

At the moment, when an IAM user doesn't have appropriate permissions to launch an instance, they may get an "encoded" authorization permission error.

This error message can be decoded using the command line / API fairly easily - but what permissions/configuration do I have to apply in order for the user to see the decoded message in the console when the launch action fails?

I've applied "sts:DecodeAuthorizationMessage", and even "sts:*" to the user, but that doesn't result in the EC2 console decoding the message for the user.  They still have to go off to the command line or wherever to get the message decoded.

Comment: To my knowledge at least, you can't.